# Third Person Camera Positioning

Tags: camera, scenekit, euler-angles

As part of my game i would like the user to be able to rotate the camera around the character. imagine the character is located at the centre of a sphere with radius r, and the camera is located somewhere on the surface of the sphere such that it is always focused at the character and the character appears upright.

I attempted to use the bellow code to implement the above but it doesnt produce the correct result for any given eulerAngle

```
func cameraHandle_orientOnNode(camera: SCNNode, target: SCNNode, eulerAngles: SCNVector3, arcLength: Float) {
    let targetPos = target.presentationNode().position
    let theta = Float(eulerAngles.x)
    let phi = Float(eulerAngles.z)
    let x = CGFloat(arcLength * sin(phi) * cos(theta)) + targetPos.x
    let y = CGFloat(arcLength * sin(phi) * sin(theta)) + targetPos.y
    let z = CGFloat(arcLength * cos(phi)) + targetPos.z
    let newPos = SCNVector3Make(x, y, z)
    camera.position = newPos
    camera.eulerAngles = eulerAngles
}
```

Comment: or both `camera` and `target` child nodes of the root node? If not, you'll have to convert between coordinate systems.

Comment: i never explicitly add the camera as a child of the root node as i do for the target. i do set it as the point of view for the scene. should i be adding the camera as a child as well as setting it as the point of view?

Comment: yes. The camera must be in the scene graph.

Comment: Does not seem to make a difference whether i add the camera as a child or not